# pip install PyQt6 producing "No matching distribution..." error

Tags: python, pyqt6

I've been trying to install PyQt6 on my Ubuntu machine, running Python 3.8.10.

Following the instructions on [the site](https://pypi.org/project/PyQt6/), I have tried the following:

[image]

I have also tried with `pip3` and I have tried installing in PyCharm:

[image]

Any suggestions on how i can satisfy the distribution they're looking for? I'm not really sure what is meant by these error messages.

Thanks!

Comment: Consider Updating your python? You seem to still be using 3.8

Comment: Okay, I could look into that. I figured it wouldn't be necessary because the site says it should work for Python >=3.6.1

Answer (score 12):

Try to update Your pip module and setuptools:

```
python3 -m pip install pip setuptools --upgrade
```

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. `python3 -m pip install pip setuptools --upgrade &&
pip3 install PyQt6`

Comment: worked for me, mint 20.3. Thanks!

Comment: I had to run this as `sudo` to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem and tried running the command with `sudo` and worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I also had problems and the following did not work:
pip install pyqt6
python3 -m pip install pip setuptools --upgrade && pip3
sudo python3 -m pip install pip setuptools --upgrade && pip3
I kept getting an error about missing testresources
I tried
pip install testresources
and then
pip install pyqt6
and worked fine.
Good Luck. This is like the blind leading the blind....

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You seem to be unaware that you can [edit] your posts, instead of adding another near identcial copy of an existing one. Please edit one and delete the other.

Answer (score -1):

I also had problems and the following did not work: pip install pyqt6. Then python3 -m pip install pip setuptools --upgrade && pip3. And then sudo python3 -m pip install pip setuptools --upgrade && pip3.  I kept getting an error about missing testresources.  I tried pip install testresources and then pip install pyqt6 and it  worked fine. I don't know how to separate the attempted commands. Carriage returns are ignored. Good Luck. This is like the blind leading the blind....

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You seem to be unaware that you can [edit] your posts, instead of adding another near identcial copy of an existing one. Please edit one and delete the other.